# Three.js vertex shader to render all geometry triangles so they face camera

Tags: three.js, vertex-shader

I would like to create a vertex shader in Three.js to render the faces of a textured geometry so that all the triangles are face-on to the camera.

This is to emulate the functionality and performance of Three.js Points, but without the size limitation of gl_PointSize.

I'm not really sure what calculation to perform in the vertex shader. Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_lookat.html use lookAt 
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/Camera

Comment: Thanks, but lookAt is ok for separate objects - I need potentially thousands of triangles in one object to face the camera, hence the vertex shader requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to add custom attribute to your geometry, easiest one to use would be a vector to the center of the triangle

in vertex shader you will have to calculate how to move each vertex, you now have

- vertex position
- vector to center
- vertex normal == face normal
- camera orientation (from matrices)

from that you can calculate the **triangle center**, which be static and calculate the rotation vertex has to make around the **triangle center** around axis perpendicular to the **vector to center** so that **normal** will come out as inverse of the **camera orientation**

the math is not very complicated, but writing shader code is tedious because of the non-existent debug - i advise you to first write a code that rotates the positions of geometry(using only the same parametres) and port it to shader

Comment: Great - thanks for this, makes complete sense.Good idea for getting this working in JS first then converting to GLSL.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I need to do something similar and any example code would be appreciated!